# Using AJAX to post checkbox list without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of checkboxes, and want to submit the value of the checkbox when it is checked to PHP. I would prefer not to have a submit button, and rather post the value each time a checkbox is checked, so that the form does not refresh and clear the checked checkbox. However, each time I click one of the checkboxes, nothing happens.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="this.form.submit();" name="form1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="1">value1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="2">value2</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="3">value3</input>
</form>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
function function1() {
    var data = $("form1").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php", 
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data) 
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have included the JQuery library.

And "test.php":

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Have you used the browsers javascript debugger (F12) to see what does happen?

Comment: Where is the PHP script called `test.php`

Comment: You haven't added the jQuery Library it seems. Put this in your code at the top:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `var data = $("form1").serialize();` you should use  `var data = $("[name='form1']").serialize()`.
Using a plain string like that won't find you anything. You must specify that you want the element with the name, 'form1'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onchange event not onclick event https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: `onclick` is successfully calling `function1()`

Comment: that may well be the case, but for the submission, you need the change event. see below, Kostandy did it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="1">value1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="2">value2</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="3">value3</input>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    var data = $("form1").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php", 
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: ({data: data}),
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data) 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.